# upload a zip file to google team drive through python api

Tags: google-drive-api, zip, google-api-python-client, gzip

I am trying to upload a bunch of zip files to a Team Drive through Python API. The weird thing is that the program works if the zip file has extension "`csv.gz`" but fails if the extension is "`.zip`". Here is the code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import uuid

from apiclient import discovery
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools

from apiclient import errors
from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload

args = tools.argparser.parse_args()
args.noauth_local_webserver = True

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
store = file.Storage('storage.json')
creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store, args)
DRIVE = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

def upload_file_to_td_folder(folder_id, fn, mimeType):
    body = {'name': fn, 'mimeType': mimeType, 'parents': [folder_id]}
    return DRIVE.files().create(body=body, media_body=fn,
            supportsTeamDrives=True, fields='id').execute().get('id')

FILE_MIME = 'application/vnd.google-apps.file'
folder_id = "abcdefg"
# file = "data_2018-09-07.csv.gz" this one works!
file = "data_2018-09-07.zip"
upload_file_to_td_folder(folder_id, file, FILE_MIME)
```

Here is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test_td.py", line 103, in <module>
     upload_file_to_td_folder(folder_id, file, FILE_MIME)
File "test_td.py", line 46, in upload_file_to_td_folder
     supportsTeamDrives=True, fields='id').execute().get('id')
File "/home/bo/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauth2client/_helpers.py", line 133, in positional_wrapper
     return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/bo/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 840, in execute
     raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri) googleapiclient.errors.HttpError:
     <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?supportsTeamDrives=true&fields=id&alt=json&uploadType=multipart
       returned "Bad Request">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the type of file extension used here.

```
file = "data_2018-09-07.csv.gz"
```

[**Gzip**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1952) is a file format for storing a single compressed file.

```
file = "data_2018-09-07.zip"
```

[**ZIP**](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT) is a file format used for storing arbitrary number of files and folders together with lossless compression.

It means gzip is only capable to compress a single file while zip compresses multiple files one by one and archives them into a single file afterwards.
So if you need a single file inside a big archive, you have to decompress the whole zip/gzip file to get the file.
In your case, you have specified the file as a csv.gz, which is more effective as compressed as a single file.

You can try here the [ZIP Extractor](https://gsuitetips.com/tips/drive/working-with-zip-files-in-drive/) extension enables efficient management of zip archives within Drive.